# Qt, change widget overlay?

Tags: c++, qt

I know I could overlay widgets by just specifying their parent child relation-ship.

But if I have two widgets, say A and B.

At first B is over A and on the bottom left corner of A.
But when a button is clicked, I want A appear over B and on the bottom left corner of B.

How could I implement this without QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `QWidget::raise()`, `QWidget::lower()`, `QWidget::move()`, `QWidget::resize()`.

Pseudo Code:

```
void slotButtonClicked()
{
    // Raize z-index to be "above"
    widgetB->raise();

    // Update size to small
    widgetB->resize( smallWidth, smallHeight );

    // Lower z-index to be "below"
    widgetA->lower();

    // Update size to large
    widgetA->resize( largeWidth, largeHeight );

    // Move smaller widget to corner
    widgetB->move( 0, widgetA->height()-widgetB->height() ); 
}
```

Comment: Then how about the parent child relationship? Who is who's child now?

Comment: I'm thinking they're both children of a container widget.

Comment: You can do that with one being the child of another, but I'm not sure it's necessary.